# PHPExcel - How to round up value?

Tags: php, windows, phpexcel

May I know what is the function to be use in order to round up the column value into 2 decimals point with percentage symbol? E.g: 1.88% instead of 1.88230293

$worksheet_details->setCellValue("D14", "=SUM((F33 / F34))");

How do I round up the value in cell D14?

---

SOLUTION:

By the way, after I keep continue look for the solution from the Internet and I got this...

```
$percentageFormat = '#.## \%;[Red]-#.## \%';
$worksheet_details->setCellValue("C14", "=SUM((C33 / C34) * 100)");
$worksheet_details->getStyle('C14')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode($percentageFormat);
```

just change the first # to 0 if you want it display in 0.xx format... or else it will display .xx only

Comment: 1.88 is 188%, 0.0188 is 1.88%. Did you make a mistake in your post?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want it to be outputted as a string:

```
echo '%'.number_format($your_number,2);
```

If you want to retain it as a numerical float value (but compromise on the percentage):

```
echo round($your_number,2);
```

If you're looking for an Excel function, use:

```
$worksheet_details->setCellValue('D14', '=TEXT(F33/F34,"0.00%")');
```

Comment: Well, instead of echoing it out, store it as a variable.

Comment: erm sorry Jamie, I think I miss out some of the thing in my question.. try to read and try assist me again?

Comment: Oh, I see - you want the Excel formula not the PHP way of doing it. I've added the solution to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for [`ROUND()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/round-a-number-HP003056144.aspx) function:

```
=ROUND(10/3; 2)
```

or, in your case:

```
$worksheet_details->setCellValue("D14", "=ROUND(SUM((F33 / F34)); 2)");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to round in PHP, with [round()](http://php.net/round) you can specify the precision you want a float number:

```
echo round(1.95583, 2) . "%";  // 1.96%
```

If you mean to round in Excel, you can use the [ROUND function](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/qt/070809_round.htm):

```
$worksheet_details->setCellValue("D14", "=TEXT(SUM((F33 / F34)), '###.##%')");
```

or

```
$worksheet_details->setCellValue("D14", "=TEXT(SUM((F33 / F34)/100), '###.##%')");
```

if the number is a percentage already.

Hope it helps.

Comment: erm sorry eljunior, I think I miss out some of the thing in my question.. try to read and try assist me again?

Comment: I'm sorry, I looked quickly at the php tag and didn't read the question appropriately. I edited my answer but I think Jamie's is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display in percent number format you can try this.

```
$percentVal = '95.6';

PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder( new PHPExcel_Cell_AdvancedValueBinder() );


$percentCell->setValue($percentVal . '%');
$sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($percentCellIndex, $dataRow)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.0%');
```

// Output 95.6% and formatted as number in Excel

Answer (score 0):

As @ariefbayu said,

```
$worksheet_details->setCellValue("D14", "=ROUND(SUM((F33 / F34)); 2)");
```

should work, but to me it threw the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception
```

so i changed the `;` for a `,`.

result:

```
$worksheet_details->setCellValue("D14", "=ROUND(SUM((F33 / F34)), 2)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the format of your cell to automatically round value to whole number.

```
$activeSheet->getStyle("A1")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('##');
```